# Can't show custom taxonomy in WordPress WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-taxonomy

I have Custom Post Types in my website, and a Custom Taxonomies inside of each.
When i use just 'post_type' in WP_Query array with a CPT name in it, it works fine, but when i want to display childrens (taxonomies) i have nothing in response.
Example structure (let's say that there are registered custom names):

```
Custom_Post1
    |--- Custom_Tax1
    |--- Custom_Tax2
Custom_Post2
    |--- Custom_Tax1
    |--- Custom_Tax2
```

Code which works GOOD:

```
$current_items_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'Custom_Post1',
);
$current_items = new WP_Query( $current_items_args );
<?php if ($current_items->have_posts()): ?>
  <?php while ($current_items->have_posts()): ?>
    <?php $current_items->the_post(); ?>
      <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Code which works BAD:

```
$current_items_args = array(
 'tax_query' => array(
    array(
     'taxonomy' => 'Custom_Tax1',
     'field'    => 'slug',
    ),
  ),
);
$current_items = new WP_Query( $current_items_args );
<?php if ($current_items->have_posts()): ?>
  <?php while ($current_items->have_posts()): ?>
    <?php $current_items->the_post(); ?>
      <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have tryed many similar posts in stackoverflow and entire google, but can't understand where is the problem. Already spent on it all day. It is possible that i put some bad  collons right here but that's not the point in my problem.

Thanks

Comment: On your second example what returns when you `var_dump( $args );` ? Also have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/ -- I'll post an answer tomorrow when I'm at my desk.

Comment: After var_dump( $args ); i have output:
`array(2) {
  ["public"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_builtin"]=>
  bool(false)
}` .
After var_dump( $current_items_args ); i have output:
`array(2) {
  ["tax_query"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["taxonomy"]=>
      string(15) "alby-kaplanskie"
      ["field"]=>
      string(4) "slug"
    }
  }
  ["paged"]=>
  int(1)
}` .

Thanks @Aliqua , i will try the link with 'get_term_children' in monday, cuz i won't be home until Monday.

Comment: Let us know how you go and we can work on something after you have tried. Best of luck !

Comment: Hi! I tried different possibilities from your link @Aliqua, including something like this:
`$terms = get_terms( array(
  'taxonomy' => 'Custom_Tax1',
  'hide_empty' => false,
) );` and `get_term_children()`, but the functions didn't display anything. I can't get those custom taxonomies out of box